# keep files in other path in batch file

Tags: batch-file, path, mono

I want to solve one question about path.
I have this code take in this forum who separetes stereo files in 2 mono files:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for %%n in (*.wav) do CALL :runsox "%%n"
GOTO :eof

:runsox
CALL :wait
START "%~1.left" C:\sox\sox.exe %~1 -c 1 %~1.left.flac remix 1
CALL :wait
START "%~1.right" C:\sox\sox.exe %~1 -c 2 %~1.right.flac remix 2
GOTO :eof

:wait
FOR /f %%c IN ('tasklist^|find /i /c "sox.exe"') DO SET running=%%c
IF %running% GEQ 6 timeout /t 5 >nul&GOTO wait
GOTO :eof
```

but I want know how is possible make a little mod to move lefts file on a subfolder eg. /left and right files in /right in the main code without needed execute other batch:

I did that in a separete batch:

```
move *.wav.left.wav left/
move *.wav.left.wav right/
```

Comment: As your code is using a recursive search, should the left and right folders be created inside each folder where a `.wav` file is found?

Comment: sorry I dont interested in recursive, so I have delete /r, I want only in actual folder. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    2>nul (
        md right
        md left
    )

    for %%a in (*.wav) do (
        call :wait 
        start "%%~na.left"  C:\sox\sox.exe "%%~fa" -c 1 "%%~dpa\left\%%~na.left.flac"   remix 1
        call :wait
        start "%%~na.right" C:\sox\sox.exe "%%~fa" -c 2 "%%~dpa\right\%%~na.right.flac" remix 2
    )
    goto :eof

:wait
    FOR /f "skip=4 tokens=5 delims=," %%p IN ('
        tasklist /fo:csv /nh /fi "imagename eq sox.exe" 
    ') do ( >nul timeout /t 5 & goto :wait )
    GOTO :eof
```

The `for` replaceable parameter `%%a` will hold the reference to the file being processed, so we can use this reference to obtain partial information (see `for /?` for the full list)

- `%%~na` is the name of the file without extension
- `%%~fa` is the full path to the file
- `%%~dpa` is the drive and path where the file is stored

Using the indicated elements, command is changed to include the output folder.